# Android Studio Room: Unable to create database file

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm trying to create a simple database in Android Studio using Room (with Java). This is for a plugin in another application, so there is no default Activity. When I go to `Device File Explorer`, the database file does not exist. Wondering if someone can point me in the correct direction?

Here's my code for creating the DB:

```
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract NoteDao NoteDao();

    private static AppDatabase noteDB;

    public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (null == noteDB) {
            noteDB = buildDatabaseInstance(context);
        }
        return noteDB;
    }

    private static AppDatabase buildDatabaseInstance(Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                AppDatabase.class,
                "exampleDB")
                .allowMainThreadQueries().build();
    }

    public void cleanUp(){
        noteDB = null;
    }

}
```

Here's my code for the DAO:

```
@Dao
public interface NoteDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM note")
    List<Note> getAll();

    @Insert
    void insert(Note note);

    @Delete
    void delete(Note note);

    @Update
    void update(Note note);
```

Here's my code for the entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "note")
public class Note {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    public String name;


    public Note(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Note)) return false;

        Note note = (Note) o;

        if (id != note.id) return false;
        return name != null ? name.equals(note.name) : note.name == null;
    }



    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
```

I am creating the database in the `onCreate` method of the entry-point of the plugin. However, when I check to see if the database exists using the function below, it always returns False.

```
    private static String doesDatabaseExist(Context context, String dbName) {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(dbName);
        String path = dbFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return dbFile.exists();
    }
```

When I go into `Device File Explorer` and and search for the path where the database file should have been created, it does not exist. It also does not show up in the Database Inspector. I've looked through a lot of tutorials & can't find anything wrong with my code. Gradle files & dependencies are all correct (I followed the Android Developer Guide) and have added permissions in the manifest as well.

Thanks!

Comment: You should start by removing `allowMainThreadQueries()`. Beyond that, are you sure that any of this code is running? What is calling `getInstance()`? Also, you probably should close the database in `cleanUp()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I go into Device File Explorer and and search for the path where the database file should have been created, it does not exist.

The likely cause (unable to say definitely) is that you have not accessed the database (e.g. used one of the dao's to add something or try to retrieve something). That is because the database is only actually created when an attempt is made to open it.

Rather than use say a Dao (eg NoteDao.getAll()) you could force an open using (for example) :-

```
private static AppDatabase buildDatabaseInstance(Context context) {

    AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(context,
            AppDatabase.class,
            "exampleDB")
            .allowMainThreadQueries().build();
    db.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase(); //<<<<< Forces an Open
    return db;
}
```

Perhaps consider the following adaptation of your code, so that 2 databases (identical bar the name and whether or not they are forced open) are opened (eventually).

Callbacks have been added so that when the onCreate and onOpen are called output signifying the happenings are written to the log.

So the modified @Database class **AppDatabase** is :-

```
@Database(entities = {Note.class},version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract NoteDao NoteDao();

    private static AppDatabase noteDB;
    public static final String TAG = "OPENINFO"; /* added */

    /* not used for demo */
    public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context, String dbName, boolean forceOpen) {
        if (null == noteDB) {
            noteDB = buildDatabaseInstance(context,dbName,forceOpen);
        }
        return noteDB;
    }

    /* made public and added ability to pass dbname and also boolean to force open or not */
    public static AppDatabase buildDatabaseInstance(Context context, String dbName, boolean forceOpen) {

        AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                AppDatabase.class,
                dbName)
                /* ADDED callbacks to allow open and create to be logged */
                .addCallback(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                        super.onCreate(db);
                        Log.d(TAG,"OnCreate callback invoked for " + dbName);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                        super.onOpen(db);
                        Log.d(TAG,"onOpen callback invoked for " + dbName);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDestructiveMigration(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                        super.onDestructiveMigration(db);
                    }
                })
                .allowMainThreadQueries().build();
        if (forceOpen) {
            db.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
        }
        return db;
    }

    /* Placed in here to keep everything together */
    /* Slightly modified and made public */
    public static String doesDatabaseExist(Context context, String dbName) {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(dbName);
        String path = dbFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return String.valueOf(dbFile.exists());
    }

    /* Will close DB if it is open */
    public void cleanUp(){
        if (noteDB != null && noteDB.isOpen()) {
            noteDB.close();
        }
        noteDB = null;
    }
}
```

Using the following code in an activity :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AppDatabase db1, db2;
    NoteDao dao1,dao2;
    private static final String db1Name = "example1";
    private static final String db2name = "example2";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /* First run then neither file should exist at this stage, subsequent runs they will exist */
        Log.d(AppDatabase.TAG,"File exists for " + db1Name + " " + AppDatabase.doesDatabaseExist(this,db1Name));
        Log.d(AppDatabase.TAG,"File exists for " + db2name + " " + AppDatabase.doesDatabaseExist(this,db2name));
        Log.d(AppDatabase.TAG,"Getting instance for " + db1Name + " not force opened");
        db1 = AppDatabase.buildDatabaseInstance(this,db1Name,false); /* not force open */
        Log.d(AppDatabase.TAG,"Getting instance for " + db2name + " force opened");
        db2 = AppDatabase.buildDatabaseInstance(this,db2name,true);
        Log.d(AppDatabase.TAG,"File exists for " + db1Name + " " + AppDatabase.doesDatabaseExist(this,db1Name));
        Log.d(AppDatabase.TAG,"File exists for " + db2name + " " + AppDatabase.doesDatabaseExist(this,db2name));
        dao1 = db1.NoteDao();
        dao2 = db2.NoteDao();
        Log.d(AppDatabase.TAG,"Dao retrieved for " + db1Name + " accessing db via Dao");
        dao1.getAll(); /* will open DB */
        Log.d(AppDatabase.TAG,"Dao retrieved for " + db2name + " accessing via Dao");
        dao2.getAll(); /* would open DB BUT DB already opened */
        Log.d(AppDatabase.TAG,"File exists for " + db1Name + " " + AppDatabase.doesDatabaseExist(this,db1Name));
        Log.d(AppDatabase.TAG,"File exists for " + db2name + " " + AppDatabase.doesDatabaseExist(this,db2name));
    }
}
```

When first run then the log includes :-

```
2021-09-21 10:47:54.405  D/OPENINFO: File exists for example1 false
2021-09-21 10:47:54.405  D/OPENINFO: File exists for example2 false
2021-09-21 10:47:54.406  D/OPENINFO: Getting instance for example1 not force opened
2021-09-21 10:47:54.415  D/OPENINFO: Getting instance for example2 force opened
2021-09-21 10:47:54.443  D/OPENINFO: OnCreate callback invoked for example2
2021-09-21 10:47:54.450  D/OPENINFO: onOpen callback invoked for example2
2021-09-21 10:47:54.450  D/OPENINFO: File exists for example1 false
2021-09-21 10:47:54.450  D/OPENINFO: File exists for example2 true
2021-09-21 10:47:54.454  D/OPENINFO: Dao retrieved for example1 accessing db via Dao
2021-09-21 10:47:54.478  D/OPENINFO: OnCreate callback invoked for example1
2021-09-21 10:47:54.483  D/OPENINFO: onOpen callback invoked for example1
2021-09-21 10:47:54.487  D/OPENINFO: Dao retrieved for example2 accessing via Dao
2021-09-21 10:47:54.490  D/OPENINFO: File exists for example1 true
2021-09-21 10:47:54.490  D/OPENINFO: File exists for example2 true
```

As can be seen the file for the example2 (forced open) exists after retrieving the instance, whilst example1 doesn't exist until the attempt is made to retrieve the data via the `getAll()`.

The output for the callbacks confirming the same.

From a DeviceExplorer perspective if the code is only (First run only) :-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    /* First run then neither file should exist at this stage, subsequent runs they will exist */
    Log.d(AppDatabase.TAG, "File exists for " + db1Name + " " + AppDatabase.doesDatabaseExist(this, db1Name));
    Log.d(AppDatabase.TAG, "File exists for " + db2name + " " + AppDatabase.doesDatabaseExist(this, db2name));
    Log.d(AppDatabase.TAG, "Getting instance for " + db1Name + " not force opened");
    db1 = AppDatabase.buildDatabaseInstance(this, db1Name, false); /* not force open */
    Log.d(AppDatabase.TAG, "Getting instance for " + db2name + " force opened");
    db2 = AppDatabase.buildDatabaseInstance(this, db2name, true);
    Log.d(AppDatabase.TAG, "File exists for " + db1Name + " " + AppDatabase.doesDatabaseExist(this, db1Name));
    Log.d(AppDatabase.TAG, "File exists for " + db2name + " " + AppDatabase.doesDatabaseExist(this, db2name));
}
```

Then Device Explorer shows :-

[image]

i.e. example2 has been created but not example1

Whilst if the full code from the activity is run (first run only) then:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing annotations for the database.
Add, this line like below:

```
@Database(entities = Note.class,version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
private static AppDatabase appsDatabase;

public static synchronized AppDatabase getAppsDatabase(Context context){
    if (appsDatabase == null){
        appsDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context,
                AppDatabase.class,
                "notes_db").build();
    }
return appsDatabase;
}
}
```

Comment: I dismissed this as it would  result in an exception e.g. `java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for a.a.so69261231javaroomwhendbgetscreated.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist`